# Struts Formatting

Tags: struts

I am trying to format a double value to two decimal places in a struts `<html:text>` tag. ex)

```
<html:text property="freight" size="9" maxlength="9" />
```

the value inside freight is a double for example $100. When it displays, it shows it as 100.0, not 100.00 (like I want it to).

I would like to display all double values to two decimal places but the `<html:text>` does not have a format property.

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<s:text>` tag to do it.

Add a formatting entry to a .properties file (probably package.properties)

```
format.twodecimalnumber={0,number,#0.00}
```

Then in your view (JSP) file, the following code can be used for displaying a formatted number

```
<s:text name="format.twodecimalnumber">
    <s:param name="value" value="53.3" />
</s:text>
```

If you want the formatted number to be displayed in an input textbox, you can wrap the above code inside a `<s:textfield>` tag. Like so -

```
<s:textfield>
    <s:param name="value">
        <s:text name="format.twodecimalnumber">
            <s:param name="value" value="53.3" />
        </s:text>
    </s:param>
</s:textfield>
```

Refer https://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/formatting-dates-and-numbers.html